# How to run script in remote terminal from text editor?

Tags: cuda, terminal, text-editor, textmate, qsub

My question is a bit specific to the scenario I'm facing. I wasn't really sure what to search for to find and answer to it here.

I'm working on developing some CUDA-based programs as part of my research. I have access to a supercomputing cluster with GPU nodes ( http://www.rcac.purdue.edu/userinfo/resources/carter/ ). And my development machine, being a 13'' late 2011 MacBook Pro, doesn't have an nVidia GPU.

There are two ways I can run CUDA apps on the node. I can either use 'qsub' to schedule a job and wait for it to run and get the output files. Or I can start an interactive shell on the gpu-node itself using the 'qsub -I' command. This has some waiting time associated with starting it, but once it starts, I can pretty much run apps in realtime as if I'm on my local machine.

Now, I use something like TextMate or TextWrangler to write my code. Is there any way I can run a command in THAT terminal ( the qsub -I one ) directly from my text editor ( or any editor ). This way, I will be able to make changes and test them much faster than manually copying the file to the server, compiling and running it there.

--
Thomas

Comment: Quite stupid question, but it never hurts to ask... Can you ssh to the cluster and edit code (in vim may be) in one window and have interactive shell in the other window?

Comment: That is doable. In fact, I can even edit the file while in the interactive shell. But the thing is, getting into the interactive shell takes time, and it times out after a while. I can use the "screen" command (like this: https://ncisf.org/index.php?q=user-guide/use-of-qsub-i-screen-and-ssh) to keep the session active over longer periods but its still not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that the newer version of [Textmate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) allow you edit content on remote machine on your local textmate installation and instantly save it on the server. This trick might save you a lot of time. Of course this is possible with most editor command line (using a simple SSH Reverse tunnel trick). But being able to continue using Textmate make rmate an even better choice.

Check out the author blog about this here. http://blog.macromates.com/2011/mate-and-rmate/

And [Ernie Miller's blog](http://erniemiller.org/2011/12/12/textmate-2-rmate-awesome/) for an awesome step by step approach.

Comment: I tried rmate, but it seems the ssh tunneling doesn't translate properly to the cluster node.

Comment: I finally found a way to get rmate to work. I can use rmate from the front-end login host I initially connect to. Since the files are synced from this host to the cluster nodes, I can use this for testing directly on the cluster. Thanks!